# Approval Process reject behavior

Tags: approval-process

I have a following scenario for approval process:

Step 1: 2 approvers(Unanimous approval required)

Step 2: 4 approvers(Unanimous approval required, Reject Behavior:Go back 1 step)

Step 3: 1 approver(Reject Behavior:Go back 1 step)

When at step 3 I reject the record it goes to 4 approvers of Step 2 but if anyone among those 4 approves the record it goes to next step without approved by other 3 approvers in step 2.
Whats the reason behind this?